# Caret inheriting the global color property on next line instead of the more specific color property

Tags: html, css, contenteditable, caret

I have a div where user can write text:

```
<div id="editable_div" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

And the style

```
<style>
 #editable_div {
  color: yellow;
  background-color: black;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 5px;
 }
 #editable_div div {
  color: yellow;
 }
</style>
```

Now, since I have text of color:#444 all over the place I also have this in my css:

```
* {
  color:#444;
 }
```

Now the issue:
When the user clicks upon the div, the caret is yellow and everything works fine, but as soon as the user hits enter to go to the next line, the caret is now #444 till the user  types the first character, in which case in goes back to yellow, and this happens for each line, each time user hits enter on his/her keybord.
This seems to be caused by * { color:#444 }, 'cause if I remove it, the caret on the next line in the div is yellow, as it should be.
Seems like the global color property acts upon the color of the caret till at least one character is typed on the line.
I'd like to fix this while keeping the global color property. How can I achieve this?

Comment: When you hit Enter the browser may be inserting a <span> or other element rather than a <div>.  Try changing "#editable_div div" in your CSS to "#editable_div *"

Comment: @phari, It works thanks. Though this is a very very inefficient selector. Is there a better way?

Comment: Instead of using the * selector for #444 can you use "body"?  The color property is inherited so it will apply to any elements that aren't explicitly given other colors.  Then you may not need to apply a style to the descendants of #editable_div at all.

Comment: I personally would not set a global color like `* { color: yellow }`. Instead, I would just put it on the body, so that way it doesn't overwrite stuff. `body { color: yellow }`

Comment: Yes thank you. Setting the body color to #444 solves this.